# How can I style the backgrounds of Bootstrap's new form-floating input labels?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.3, and trying to use the new "floating labels".  I would like my inputs to have additional styling, such as background colors.  When I add a subtle green background color at first, it looks fine when there is no value set, but as soon as you focus in or add text, you get this:

[image]

If I add a background color to the label, it doesn't style the white part there, it styles some region surrounding it:

[image]

Does this have something to do with :before/:after? Will someone please shed some light on this black magic?  I am using Brave, and it needs to work in Brave.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="w-25 p-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" " id="myElement" style="background-color: var(--bs-success-bg-subtle); color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis); border-color: var(--bs-success-border-subtle);">
        <label class="form-label" for="myElement" style="color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis); background-color: red;">Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can shed the light yourself - inspect the input field using your browser dev tools, and use "Force element state" to set the `:focus` state. Then the label will go into the floating position, and if you then inspect it, you will see that the white background is indeed from an absolute positioned `::after` element.

Answer (score 5):

The background has the same color as the input. So it needs to be reset after the input gets his `:focus`.

If you want to keep the smaller label red; add another background on the `label:after` when `input:focus`.

The issue is that you don't want to background on the `label` if there is some content. Currently you can use the [`placeholder-show`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown) property, which is quite well supported as shown on [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder-shown).

```css
.form-floating > input:not(:focus):placeholder-shown + label {
     background: red;
}

.form-floating > input + label:after {
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="w-25 p-3">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" " id="myElement" style="background-color: var(--bs-success-bg-subtle); color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis); border-color: var(--bs-success-border-subtle);">
        <label class="form-label" for="myElement" style="color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis);">Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing the helpful notes.  My issue is that the background color is NOT the same color as the input, out of the box when I change the background color.  With the code you provided, when you deselect the input after putting text in it, you end up with the outer border thing again.

Comment: Please see my edit, I think this is what you're looking for m8!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the CBroe and 0stone0, I was able to poke around in the inspector to find the bootstrap CSS selector doing the damage:

[image]

Then, I could right-click that selector, and add my own class name to control the color of any floating label inputs I want across the site

```css
.form-floating.float_success > .form-control-plaintext ~ label::after,
.form-floating.float_success > .form-control:focus ~ label::after,
.form-floating.float_success > .form-control:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label::after,
.form-floating.float_success > .form-select ~ label::after {
    background: var(--bs-success-bg-subtle);
    color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="w-25 p-3">
    <div class="form-floating float_success">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" " id="myElement" style="background-color: var(--bs-success-bg-subtle); color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis); border-color: var(--bs-success-border-subtle);">
        <label class="form-label" for="myElement" style="color: var(--bs-success-text-emphasis);">Name</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the red color to make the issue stand out more.

Comment: I didn't want the label to be red - I wanted to be able to control the label's color. I used red to clearly demonstrate that I could not control the label's color.

Comment: Your answer doesn't correspond to your question, as I interpret the question. Maybe your question needs more clarity.